# YUI autocomplete url local datasource

Tags: javascript, yui

I have an array that resides on the same domain as my html and I want to use the array as the source for an autocomplete textbox. Contents of `myarr.json` (1 MB):

```
["Aaronsburg, PA", "Abanda, AL", "Abbeville, AL", "Abbeville, GA" ... ]
```

I am using YUI2: [AutoComplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/#start) and it works if I *embed* (a portion of) the array like this:

```
var myDataSource = 
    new YAHOO.util.LocalDataSource(["Aaronsburg, PA", "Abanda, AL"]);
```

but my array is huge so I must link to it. When I do that:

```
var myDataSource = 
    new YAHOO.util.LocalDataSource("http://mydomain.com/myarr.json");
```

the console responds: `GET http://mydomain.com/myarr.json/search/aarons/other/data 404 (Not Found)`

How do I turn my array into json that can respond to the `/search` component of that GET statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "link" to it, you should just use the [Remote Datasource](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_basic_xhr.html).

The [Examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/index.html) go through how to [Customize](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_xhr_customrequest.html) your datasource parsing.

YUI has very extensive documentation on all of this.

**[Edit]**

In response to your comment, see the [Datasource Docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/#schemas)

Mainly under "Simple JavaScript Array",

```
myDataSource.responseSchema = {
    fields: ["name"]
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Since my json file is a simple array, how do I rewrite this line from the example?: `oDS.responseSchema = {resultsList : "ResultSet.Result",fields : ["Title"]};`